# tweepy.errors.BadReque st: 400 Bad Request 215 - Bad Authentication data. THIS APPEARS WHEN I TRY TO USE "api.home_timeline( )"

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-code, tweepy

I am trying to make a twitter bot, but when I run it shows this in the terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Pedro\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\PROJETOS\BOTTMADULOVER\BOT.py", line 20, in <module>
    ptwitts = api.home_timeline()
  File "C:\Users\Pedro\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\tweepy\api.py", line 33, in wrapper
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Pedro\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\tweepy\api.py", line 46, in wrapper
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Pedro\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\tweepy\api.py", line 331, in home_timeline
    return self.request(
  File "C:\Users\Pedro\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\tweepy\api.py", line 267, in request
    raise BadRequest(resp)
tweepy.errors.BadRequest: 400 Bad Request
215 - Bad Authentication data.
```

```py
import tweepy
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')

api_key = config['twitter']['api_key']
api_key_secret = config['twitter']['api_secret']

access_token = config['twitter']['acess_token']
access_token_secret = config['twitter']['acess_token_secret']

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(api_key,api_key_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token,access_token_secret)

api= tweepy.API(auth)


ptwitts = api.home_timeline()

print(ptwitts)
```